# printing odd and even number using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I know there are many examples for my question. However, I want to understand why 1 program that I wrote works and other doesn't.

Here is what I have written.

```
void * even()
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if(count % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("count %d\n",count);
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
        }
            count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        if(count >= 100) return NULL;
    }
}


void * odd()
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if(count % 2 == 1)
        {
            printf("count %d\n",count);
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
        }
            count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        if(count >= 100) return NULL;
    }
}
```

So the above piece of code prints only 0 or 0 and 1 sometimes. However the below code works fine.

```
void * even()
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if(count % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("count %d\n",count);
            count++;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        if(count >= 100) return NULL;
    }
}


void * odd()
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if(count % 2 == 1)
        {
            printf("count %d\n",count);
            count++;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        if(count >= 100) return NULL;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, some variation of the below may happen:

1. `even()` acquires the lock
2. `even()` prints `count` (which is 0) and signals the condition (though `odd()` can't wake until `even()` releases the lock)
3. `even()` increments `count` to 1
4. `even()` releases the lock, and `odd()` wakes.
5. `odd()` increments `count` to 2
6. `odd()` releases the lock (but hasn't signalled the condition)
7. `odd()` acquires the lock
8. `odd()` waits, because `count` is even (== 2)... now both threads are waiting and neither can signal the condition.

Things may happen slightly differently depending on which thread goes first, but both threads still get stuck in a way similar to the above.

Both examples are unreliable, though, because they don't account for spurious wakeups when waiting for the condition.  Normally a loop should be used to retry the wait if the desired wakeup conditions aren't met, holding the lock the whole time so a signal won't be missed:

```
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        /* ...stuff... */
            /* Use a loop to restart the wait if it was interrupted early */
            while(count % 2 != 0)
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
        /* ...stuff... */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply/. I am not fully convinced. Why will odd not signal just after printing. Please let me know about more safer ways to do this.

Comment: @rohit **IF** `odd()` printed, it would signal.. but `count` is incremented twice between `odd()`'s wait and the `if` in the next loop pass -- once by `even()` before `odd()` wakes, then again by `odd()` after it wakes... so when `odd()` gets to the `if` again, it just waits again (since `count` is even) instead of printing and signalling.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, in `even()`, then if count is odd, you `pthread_cond_signal` `odd()` to run if `count` is even. `count` will be incremented, and the mutex dropped. At this point `odd()` may run and signal `even()` before `even()` ever reaches the `pthread_cond_wait()`. Now `odd()` will never again signal `even()` (because `count` is now even), and the `even()`'s `pthread_cond_wait()` will never exit.

But both of your examples are buggy. You are (last full line) reading `count` outside the mutex that protects it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<iostream>
void *odd(void* data);
void *even(void* data);
static int count=0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
int main()
{

   pthread_t thread1,thread2;

   pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,&even,0);

   pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,&odd,0);

   pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
   pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

   return 0;
}




void *even(void* data)
{

   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while(count< 10)
   {
      while(count%2!=0)
      {
         pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
      }

      std::cout<<count;
      count++;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
   }
   pthread_exit(0);
}

void *odd(void* data)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while(count<10)
   {
      while(count%2!=1)
      {
         pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
      }

      std::cout<<count;
      count++;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
   }
   pthread_exit(0);
}
```